# IIS 7 - 1 host, 2 domains . Once domain with a different route

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have 2 domain names: domain1.com and domain2.com

My ASP.NET MVC 2 site is hosted at domain1.com

I need "domain2.com" to goto "domain1.com/path" but also need to keep the domain2.com in the URL box for routing purposes. I have tried forwarding but this doesn't work because if I click links, etc on the site it will really use domain1.com URL.

Can I use URL rewrite to have anything coming from domain2.com to really goto "domain2.com/path" or?

Also I assume I need to point the nameservers to domain2.com as well?

Comment: Your question is very unclear.  How exactly can you expect domain2.com to go to two different places?

Comment: @Mystere Man - I updated the example, hopefully that helps. I wanted it to go to domain1.com/path not domain2.com/path

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the site respond to both domains.  You need to set your DNS to resolve to the same IP for both sites, then make sure your server responds to both domains.  You typically do this by altering the hostheader field, and add multiple bindings.

Then you can use URL rewriting in your routing to make it go to the right places.

Answer (score -1):

Consider using **[UrlRewrite](http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite)** module for IIS

> IIS URL Rewrite 2.0 enables Web administrators to create powerful
>   rules to implement URLs that are easier for users to remember and
>   easier for search engines to find. By using rule templates, rewrite
>   maps, .NET providers, and other functionality integrated into IIS
>   Manager, Web administrators can easily set up rules to define URL
>   rewriting behavior based on HTTP headers, HTTP response or request
>   headers, IIS server variables, and even complex programmatic rules. In
>   addition, Web administrators can perform redirects, send custom
>   responses, or stop HTTP requests based on the logic expressed in the
>   rewrite rules.

Comment: Yes I know about this but how do I go about doing that?